# PHP cors issue when sending image

Tags: javascript, php, ajax, cors

I have the following JS:

```
const formData = new FormData();
formData.append('email', 'some email');
formData.append('photo', 'base64 encoded image');

fetch(endpoint, {
  body: formData,
  method: 'POST',
  mode: 'cors'
}).then(response => response.json())
  .then((re) => {
     console.log(re);
}).catch((error) => {
   console.log('error', error);
});
```

And my PHP script has this on top:

```
if (isset($_SERVER['HTTP_ORIGIN'])) {
  header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin: {$_SERVER['HTTP_ORIGIN']}");
  header('Access-Control-Allow-Credentials: true');
  header('Access-Control-Max-Age: 86400');
}

if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'OPTIONS') {

  if (isset($_SERVER['HTTP_ACCESS_CONTROL_REQUEST_METHOD']))
      header("Access-Control-Allow-Methods: GET, POST, OPTIONS");         

  if (isset($_SERVER['HTTP_ACCESS_CONTROL_REQUEST_HEADERS']))
      header("Access-Control-Allow-Headers: {$_SERVER['HTTP_ACCESS_CONTROL_REQUEST_HEADERS']}");

  exit(0);
}
```

and this, further down:

```
if (isset($_POST['photo'])) {
  if (!empty($_POST['photo'])) {
    $photo = base64_decode(preg_replace('#^data:image/\w+;base64,#i', '', $_POST['photo']);
$mail->addStringAttachment($photo, "Photo.png", "base64", "image/png");
  }
}
```

When I do the post, I get a cors error (Reason: CORS header ‘Access-Control-Allow-Origin’ missing). However, if I comment out the part of the php script which handles the photo (last snippet above), the script runs fine and sends the email. If I uncomment it, I get the same cors error again.
When I just switch from async frontend to a classic request, it works fine with the photos. I'd understand if there's an issue with how I send the photo in the async mode, but why the cors issue here?

EDIT:

After some fiddling with `$_POST['photo']`, I managed to get a normal error message: `JSON.parse: unexpected non-whitespace character after JSON data at line 1 column 24024 of the JSON data`, which would means something is wrong with my photo, but when I inspect the network tab, I see I have `{ "email": "some email", "photo": "a very long base64 encoded string" }` which look OK.

Comment: This really makes no sense. As you've rightly pointed out, this bit of processing _should_ have nothing to do with how the CORS headers are issued by the server, unless you've somehow got am error. By any chance when you get the CORS error do you also get accompanying HTTP status error, maybe? Does your application try to automatically redirect to an error page when an exception occurs? That could screw up the output. I can't think what else it could be, unless there's some other logical issue in your script - it might make sense to show us the rest of it, so we can see exactly what goes on.

Comment: Are you expecting the origin to be the same as the endpoint? If so, instead of cors mode use `same-origin` mode.

Comment: No, the origin is not the same, but as @ADyson said and I agree, this must be a different issue, it makes no sense for it to be a cors issue when I can clearly get it to work without the photo.

Comment: @ADyson please see my edit above

Comment: `JSON.parse` looks like a client-side error (because JSON.parse is a JavaScript function)...to me it implies a problem with the response coming back from PHP. Exactly where are you seeing that data in the Network tab? Is it your response? (And are you still getting a CORS error simultaneously?). And which line of code does the console say is causing it?

Comment: @ADyson I get the error in the `.catch()` part of the fetch. If I just try accessing `$_POST['photo']` on the backend, the error appears without the cors error and the email is sent (without the photo, of course). However, if I try sending the photo as an attachment, I get both the JSON.parse error AND the cors error and the email does not get sent.

Comment: Ok well that raises a question about whether the code snippet above (within the `if (!empty($_POST['photo'])) {` block) can affect what your script returns back to the browser? Is it the case that it change change the output of the PHP script?

Comment: @ADyson no, I just have `echo json_encode(array('response_text' => 'Sent'));`if the email is sent and the same thing with `Not sent` if it's not sent, for now. But if I access `$_POST['photo']`, none of those two get back to the client. If I don't access it, I get a proper response from the correct echo that the email is sent.

Comment: Ok so a) where are you seeing `{ "email": "some email", "photo": "a very long base64 encoded string" }` exactly, then? It wasn't clear. and b) what do you mean by "accessing" `$_POST["photo"]` exactly? What code counts to you as "accessing" it? And what is the minimum amount of code you need to remove before the error goes away? c) I noticed a small thing... `$mail->addStringAttachment($photo1, "Photo.png", "base64", "image/png");` ...where does `$photo1` come from here? On the previous line you create `$photo` but not `$photo1`...

Comment: @ADyson a) I don't see it now, my mistake, I used to see it before when I was sending the data as json data, not as form data, b) accessing it - reading it, like so: `$rawPhoto = $_POST['photo'];` and removing that is the minimum that makes the error go away. I do not need to remove the `if` block in order for the error to disappear.

Comment: `$rawPhoto = $_POST['photo'];` ...your snippet above (in the question) doesn't contain that line, so that's a bit confusing. Have you changed your code since you posted that? Please keep us up to date. Also you forgot to address point c) in my last comment :-)

Comment: @ADyson `$rawPhoto = $_POST['photo'];` is just the simplest line I could write to cause the error. I don't need it in my code, but it does the trick of triggering the issue, same as it does when I use `$_POST['photo']` in the `$photo = base64_decode...` line. Yeah, about c) that's a typo from old code, it's just `photo.`, I need to edit that part.

Comment: Ok. Does php log any errors when the CORS/JSON error triggers? Another thing which might help us debug it is to try and run this without CORS getting in the way...could you [temporarily disable CORS in your browser](https://www.google.com/search?q=chrome+cors+disable) and test it again? It might be easier to see what PHP outputs. Or temporarily run your fetch() request from the same domain as the PHP, if you can.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/197527/discussion-between-dnmh-and-adyson).